# python plot ledged? unwanted labels None,None resulting from groupby() function

Tags: python, plot, group-by, line-plot

** Problem **

Plot is working fine. Need to remove "None, None" from display on plot. Perhaps this is some default legend, how to set to NULL or customize or remote.

** Python Plot Code **

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,10.5))
df_select = employee_5years.drop(['Age','Years.of.Service','County.Code','YEAR','Tenure.Years','Assigned_Department'],axis=1)
df_select = df_select.loc[(df_select['Gender'] == 'F')]
df_select = df_select.loc[(df_select['Department'].str.contains('DEPARTMENT E'))]
x_select = df_select.groupby(['YEAR.year']).agg({'Base.Pay': ['median']})
x_select.plot(title='Female Salaries Increase by E Department in last 5 Years')
plt.ylabel('Median Base Salary')
plt.xlabel('Department E by Year')
plt.show()
x_select
```

** Plot image need to remove "None, None", OR find another suitable plot configuration line chart without the None,None in the output.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Plot has a legend, and I had forgotten to set legend to None: hence the solution: plot(title="", legend=None)